# Twilio Too many requests when i am sending only one call

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I have implemented twilio email verification with send grid. Initially it was working fine but now when i send even a single request it says "Too many requests" My api code is as follow

```
twilioClient.verify
        .services("VAXXXXXXXXXX") 
        .verifications.create({to: result.email, channel: "email"})
        .then(verification => {
          console.log(verification.sid);
        });
```

Why am I getting this even i not sending in bulk? I have already googled this error and its happening in bulk calls.

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent blog that may be helpful. If not, I suggest opening a support ticket with Twilio via the Twilio Console (upper right under the ? icon, submit a ticket).

[How to test Twilio Verify without getting rate limited](https://www.twilio.com/blog/test-verify-no-rate-limits)